# My player dashing is not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**(This is my first question ever)**

I am new to unity and I am making a 2d platformer game.

I made all of the movement already and now im making animations (Idle, Run, Jump etc.) for my player. So now when I press dash button my character dashes but my sword (sword is attached to the player) goes flying down. When the dash stops my sword teleports back to the player.

I made it so when i dash my "Animator" stops and when player stops dashing the Animator starts to work again and my animations continue to play (Idle, Moving). Because if I dont do that my Player stops mid air when i dash.

So basically when I dash my Animator stops and my sword goes flying, then Animator starts and my sword comes back.

Here is the code for dashing:

```
public IEnumerator Dash() 
{
    animator.enabled = false;
    canDash = false;
    isDashing = true;
    float originalGravity = rb.gravityScale;
    rb.gravityScale = 0 f;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * dashingPower, 0 f);
    tr.emitting = true;
    yield
    return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
    tr.emitting = false;
    rb.gravityScale = originalGravity;
    isDashing = false;
    yield
    return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCooldown);
    canDash = true;
    animator.enabled = true;
}
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like your sword's position has controlled by both the `Animator` component and physics. Usually `Animator` blocks any changes for keys controlled by it. So disabling Animator allows anyone to change the position of the sword. I suspect from your description that after Animator is disabled, its `Rigidbody` is controlled by gravity and falls down.

Comment: It worked, Thank you so much this was my 5th day of just trying to fix the player dash I almost quit.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`